# Substitution of variables from JSON response (from uri) in ansible playbook to create local users account

Tags: json, variables, ansible, uri

I have JSON as output for query into CMDB, which contains informations about local users like UID, GID etc. And I would like to substitute them in ansible playbook to create those account. I know how to use it as one variable. But I would like to use it for more variables as parameters - one value from key for UID, GID, ssh public key etc. Example of JSON is attached.
Any suggestion or help?

JSON answer

```
$ curl -s -k "https://cmdb.test.loc/api/getusers.php" | jq -r '.'
{
  "users": [
    {
      "login": "johnd",
      "description": "John Doe",
      "uid": "9004",
      "sshpubkey": "ssh-rsa AAsQxHUC4mshf+mXy3+Evtd1l9/x/DF5tR1AMI9i0CQoggxX6GbxRb+lYVySUmCgnMqT/dVcOlL3ETzSnubeoC3o4Yjv9Q1NLrw== johnd@lin.x"
    },
    {
      "login": "thomasm",
      "description": "Thomas Mann",
      "uid": "9003",
      "sshpubkey": "ssh-rsa AAAdUG4PPLzrJo/M5StBXsgUcUQAPuU4y1vXIJIw+o5mx/IkxpZVvbWTqx6HbLJD8CL5jp4wpXb1UGjyYorvumrGyArYWAXWOQZNdzsIeTp1Z9tZb0qoVkGX1aR1HGst36FbcYDTB3yEmliYHSNQ== thomasm@lin.x"
    },
    {
      "login": "trib",
      "description": "Three Be",
      "uid": "9002",
      "sshpubkey": "ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzpyNyRsdvthGYzkm0rvEug1RRwURWZ9d++TzJtoWZrCKw7Ec8PJGgNJvHRAvFdSJ8mKXAK3U0WIc46P2Ij7BJzCR4o900Sad/qeYSlY7xL+oW+nXWPUuxCVT25pHAeTJDjHeHJmpqDpHGg8sLmQMXtwCb5r6YxFUOUSlM1L2Q2iVedC/IXKMTFP+7Wp9YvPX75MVjMWc6L1xCZMsBk+dQ== 3be@lin.x"
    }
  ]
}
```

Begin of playbook.yml

```
 ---
 - hosts: all
   tasks:
   - name: Take information about actual users from CMDB
     uri:
       url: "https://cmdb.test.loc/api/getusers.php"
       validate_certs: false
       method: GET
       status_code: 200,400
       body_format: json
       return_content: yes
     register: cmdb_users

   - name: Filter and rename variables from source list
     debug:
       msg: "{{ cmdb_users.json | json_query('users[*].{login: login, description: description, uid: uid, sshpubkey: sshpubkey}') }}"
   - set_fact:
       users: "{{ cmdb_users.json | json_query('users[*].{login: login, description: description, uid: uid, sshpubkey: sshpubkey}') }}"

...
```

I would like have any suggestion for next steps to use it for account creating:

```
- name : Create local users
  user: 
    name : {{ ??? }}
    uid : {{ ??? }}
    comment : {{ ??? }}
```

I know that authorized-keys file have to be created by other way, but I think, that it can be created as shell "echo" to specific file to specific path composed from variables.

Answer (score 0):

The loop below should do the job

```
- name: Create local users
  user:
    name: "{{ item.login }}"
    uid: "{{ item.uid|int }}"
    comment: "{{ item.description }}"
  loop: "{{ users }}"
```

Next loop will store the public keys to the files in `pub_key_dir`

```
- name: Store public keys to files
  copy:
    dest: "{{ pub_key_dir }}/{{ item.login }}.sshpubkey"
    content: |
      {{ item.sshpubkey }}
  loop: "{{ users }}"
```

---

Notes

1) The correct name of the module is [user](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/user_module.html#user-manage-user-accounts)

2) In the playbook, the registered variable is `cmdb_users`. The correct list is probably

```
loop: "{{ cmdb_users.json.users }}"
```

Comment: Many thanks Vladimir, your quick answer is very helpful to me!

Comment: Thanks for notes too. First was my "typo" I already corrected it. And thanks for explain in second.